# Disabling Jetty TimeoutException warning messages in logs

Tags: java, log4j, jetty

I'm trying to hide these timeout exceptions, but they keep showing up in the log -

```
2015-07-13 09:56:13.019:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp636718812-758: /feed
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:408)
        at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:70)
        at net.bull.javamelody.CounterResponseStream.write(CounterResponseStream.java:83)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1848)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:447)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:45)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:21)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:557)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:466)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:557)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:466)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2242)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-13 09:56:13.020:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp636718812-758: https://example.com/feed?queryparams=values
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:408)
        at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:70)
        at net.bull.javamelody.CounterResponseStream.write(CounterResponseStream.java:83)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1848)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:447)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:45)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:21)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:557)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:466)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:557)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:466)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:132)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:94)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2242)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:185)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1684)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:165)        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:208)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1055)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:291)        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-13 09:56:13.020:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp636718812-758: Could not send response error 500: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30000/30000 ms
```

Here's my log4j.properties -

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, S

log4j.appender.S = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.S.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %t %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.logger.oejs.Request=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler=ERROR
```

Any idea why it keeps showing on my logs?

Comment: Try to add this line `http.timeout=300000` to your jetty start file  `${jetty.base}/start.ini` !!

Comment: @Maraboc he doesn't want timeouts to go away, he just doesn't want them logged with all that stacktrace detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty has its own logging system, and doesn't automatically know about your log4j.properties file.  You can [read the documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-logging.html) on how to [set up Jetty to use Log4j](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/example-logging-log4j.html), or if you want to use Jetty's built-in logging, you can either add the following lines to your jetty-logging.properties:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.LEVEL=OFF
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.LEVEL=OFF
```

or pass them in on the command-line when starting Jetty:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.LEVEL=OFF -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.LEVEL=OFF
```

Comment: It is configured to use log4j (as instructed at that guide) and I've made sure that `log4j.properties` does actually affect logging. But nevertheless I've tried adding configuration to `jetty-logging.properties`, let's see if it works.

Comment: Okay, I thought that you hadn't followed that guide because your ConversionPattern doesn't match the format of your Exception output.

Comment: You got a point, but it's just for that row, for some reason. Other rows use the described format: `2015-07-19 04:10:52 qtp1586600255-3919 CoreLogic [DEBUG] User ...`

Comment: Further more, I managed to stop it by changing `log4j.rootCategory=WARN, S` to `ERROR` level. So my bet I was trying to change the log level of the wrong class before.

Comment: I had the wrong class name, sorry.  You partially corrected it from `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerHandler` to `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServerHandler`, but it's really `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler`.  Make sure you have the right one in your `jetty-logging.properties`.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Also, I can't explain getting it to work by changing it to `ERROR` level, but if the format is off, I'd suspect that it's not configured correctly.  A `CoreLogic` line isn't enough to verify that it's using your configuration; it needs to be a Jetty class.  Like if you see a `2015-07-19 00:54:16.428:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @35458ms` when starting then that's the default format for Jetty so it's not using your log4j config.  But anyway if it isn't using your log4j, the `jetty-logging.properties` way should work as long as the class name is correct.

Comment: You may be right, it seems that changing global level to `ERROR` wasn't the sole reason for it to work, I've also installed the `logging` module which was missing. It may have cause jetty to ignore `log4j.properties`.